# How to avoid rounding of a long value on client side?

Tags: javascript, java, json, long-integer, postman

Using Play Framework.

**Controller**

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result getResponseJson(Long id){
    List<DataField> entities = new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, DataField.class)
      .where("response_id = " + id).findList();
    Response response = new Response(entities, id);
    return ok(toJson(response));
}
```

The `Response` entity is:

```
public class Response {
  private Long uuid;
  private Map<TableField, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  ...constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

I check the response with POSTMAN. On the tab "Raw" I got:

```
{"uuid":3942015886343226874,"map":{"Work":"Contract","locale":"Mogilev"}}
```

On the tab "Pretty":

```
{
  "uuid": 3942015886343227000,
  "map": {
    "Work": "Contract",
    "locale": "Mogilev"
  }
}
```

**Why the uuid is got rounded?**

Comment: Max Number in js is +/- 9007199254740992. JS allows only 16 significant digits in a number.

Comment: The only solution I see is to use uuid as a String in java, so it will display and operate like a string, so the value won't be changed. But anyhow in other functions JS can position this like a number, so will round it...

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to Playframework it is a browser issue. Open the developer console in your browser and try this -

```
var c = 3942015886343226874;
console.log(c);
```

This will print -  3942015886343227000

because of number limit in JavaScript.

Its better to use String in case of UUID.